# ensure safe vaccines arrive as soon as possible

Tags: grammar

Is the structure of the phrase "ensure safe vaccines arrive" "ensure (**that**) safe vaccines arrive"? That is, "that" is omitted. Otherwise, "ensure safe vaccines to arrive" or "ensure safe vaccines arriving" is expected. I am not sure.

> Tsai Ing-wen (President of the Republic of China) tweeted:

The people & government of #Taiwan stand united against COVID-19, & are working together to **ensure safe vaccines arrive as soon as possible.** Thank you to all Taiwanese for your cooperation & patience in this key time.

[Source](https://twitter.com/iingwen/status/1399694742481358850)

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why  "ensure safe vaccines to arrive" or "ensure safe vaccines arriving" is incorrect.

Comment: Because they are not grammatical English!

Comment: After "ensure" we need a noun object. "that safe vaccines arrive" is a noun clause. The other two are not noun phrases

Comment: @gotube:  As I see it, in both "ensure safe vaccines to arrive" or "Ensure safe vaccines arriving", "ensure" is followed by "safe vaccines" which is a noun object. "To arrive" and "arriving" are both the enlargement of the object that points to the state of it.  So sorry, your reason doesn't convince me.

Answer (score 1):

@gotube, it is not relative clause, but nominal that clause, that is why "that" is ellipted. Aso, relative clauses function as a adjective and they post-modify the noun phrase, but this clause modify the verb "ensure".

You're correct when identifying that there is ellipsis of "that". It is the most typical example of structural ellipsis.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. I deleted that comment and have made a new one. Thanks! Your answer here reads more like a comment than an answer to the question. Care to move it to the comments area?